# Cannot launch Google Closure compiler

Tags: java, google-closure-compiler

I must be missing something obvious, but i can't even start it:

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   com.google.javascript.rhino.Messages, locale en_US    at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.google.javascript.rhino.SimpleErrorReporter.getMessage(SimpleErrorReporter.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.rhino.SimpleErrorReporter.getMessage0(SimpleErrorReporter.java:98)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.RhinoErrorReporter.(RhinoErrorReporter.java:142)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.RhinoErrorReporter.(RhinoErrorReporter.java:30)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.RhinoErrorReporter$OldRhinoErrorReporter.(RhinoErrorReporter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.RhinoErrorReporter$OldRhinoErrorReporter.(RhinoErrorReporter.java:230)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.RhinoErrorReporter.forOldRhino(RhinoErrorReporter.java:191)
>     at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.(Compiler.java:243)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.createCompiler(CommandLineRunner.java:1825)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.AbstractCommandLineRunner.doRun(AbstractCommandLineRunner.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.AbstractCommandLineRunner.run(AbstractCommandLineRunner.java:506)
>     at
>   com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner.main(CommandLineRunner.java:1998)
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -DLC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

tried with different locale options, similar errors.
Have googled around, it appears as common error in java apps.
What's a secret?

Comment: How are you launching it? Where did you obtain the compiler from?

Comment: @Chad  
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Binary-Downloads  

set O=--compilation_level SIMPLE  
set O=%O% --language_in ECMASCRIPT5  
set O=%O% --assume_function_wrapper true  
set O=%O% --js "source.js" --js_output_file "target.js"  

rem ===== Tried various options here, incl. nothing at all =====  
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF8  
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
set LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
set LC_ALL=%LANG%  
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=%_JAVA_OPTIONS% -DLC_ALL=%LC_ALL%  
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar closure-compiler-v20190106.jar %O%